# AngularJS Directive's controller randomly gets called before/after parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

(ANGULAR VERSION: 1.3.8)

I am getting an exception on a call within my directive's controller 'randomly'.  The exception happens when the directive's controller gets called BEFORE the parent's controller and the parent controller scope variable used in the directive's controller is not yet initialized.  However, on the 'random' occasion that my parent controller does get called BEFORE my directive's controller, and thus scope var is initialized, the call works and no exception is thrown. I have two questions (I have sample code below.):

1. Why is there 'randomness' in the sequence of calls between the directives's controller and the parent controller? I.e., why does one get called before/after the other?
2. I am able to eliminate the random sequence by a slight change in the HTML and by using ng-repeat on an array of length 1 in my html as opposed to passing in a single object to my directive. The directive code remains the same.

NOTE: The parent controller has a service to an ajax call injected (o_conversationService). The $scope.thread variable mentioned below relies on data returned from the ajax call.  Perhaps, the randomness is rooted on the ajax callback timing although I'm not clear how.  Regardless, this doesn't explain why the minor change in HTML removes the problem.

Below are two HTML snippets (the first working randomly and the second reliably) both using the same directive code:

HTML RANDOM (NOT)WORKING SCENARIO: With this HTML, the cfThread directive's controller gets called BEFORE parent controller and an exception is thrown because '$scope.thread' is null (see directive controller code below):

- HTML snippet (directive name: 'cf-thread'):

  ```
  <cf-thread thread = "o_conversationService.o_thread"></cf-thread>
  ```

HTML WORKING SCENARIO: With this HTML, the cfThreads directive controller gets called AFTER the parent's controller so '$scope.thread' is properly initialized (see directive controller code below):

- HTML snippet (directive name: 'cf-thread'):

  ```
  <cf-thread ng-repeat="threadObject in o_conversationService.o_threadCollection.objectDict" thread="threadObject"></cf-thread>
  ```

DIRECTIVE JS (Exception!!! marked below. Exception because $scope.thread is null):

```
    threadDirectiveModule.directive('cfThread', ['$sce', function ($sce) {

    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope: { 
            thread: '=' 
        },

        templateUrl: 'partials/directives/thread.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {

            //EXCEPTION!!! $scope.thread is null if parent controller
            //wasn't called first.
            var unsafeDirectLink = cf.Utilities.createExternalDirectLink($scope.thread.dataJSON.source.type, 
                                                  $scope.thread.dataJSON.source.user_id,
                                                  $scope.thread.dataJSON.source.root_id)

            if (cf.Utilities.isDefined(unsafeDirectLink)) {

                $scope.thread.safeDirectLink = $sce.trustAsHtml(unsafeDirectLink);
            }
            else {
                $scope.thread.safeDirectLink = null;
            }       
        }
      };
    }]);
```

FINAL NOTE: In the non-working HTML scenario, I can always add a $watch to '$scope.thread' in the directive's controller.  Needless to say, although it works, I would like to avoid it if not necessary, as seen the the working HTML scenario.

I appreciate your thoughts and patience!

Comment: Did you tried to setup the priority? https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/docs/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: No priority set.  Please note, this works with a minor modification as noted--which brings me to the questions I asked.

Comment: Ok, then set the priority to make your directive render and call after the parent controller